# Download file from url and upload into ftp

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, c#-2.0

I have a requirement that I need to download a file from an URL and need to upload that file into ftp.
I followed the below approach.

```
pdfMemoryStream=  new MemoryStream(client.DownloadData("http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg"));
FtpUploadString(pdfMemoryStream, "ftp://192.168.1.1/SampleFiles/", "FTPUserName", "Password");

private static string FtpUploadString(MemoryStream memStream, string to_uri, string user_name, string password)
{
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(to_uri);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    request.Credentials =
        new NetworkCredential(user_name, password);
    request.UseBinary = true;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[memStream.Length];
    memStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    memStream.Close();
    using (Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

I am getting below exception

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in
>   System.dll
>
> Additional information: The requested URI is invalid for this FTP
>   command.

Comment: What is your specific problem?

Comment: Exception :
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The requested URI is invalid for this FTP command.

Comment: Try passing in a uri instead of string. See if that helps...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is that your url is missing the file name. If I remember correctly you must pass the file name in the URL. So it would look something like this:

```
"ftp://192.168.1.1/SampleFiles/file.txt"
```

Comment: Took me a stupid amount of time to get to the bottom of my issue, which was exactly this. `you must pass the file name in the URL`. Thanks